# Some clarification on numpy indexing needed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I have the following numpy arrays:

```
        boxIDx = 3
        index = np.array([boxIDs!=boxIDx]).reshape(-1,1)
        print('\nbboxes:\t\n', bboxes)
        print('\nboxIDs:\t\n', boxIDs)
        print('\nIndex:\t\n', index)
```

The output is:

```
    bboxes: 
     [[370 205  40  40]
      [200 100  40  40]
      [ 30  50  40  40]]
    boxIDs: 
     [[1]
      [2]
      [3]]
    Index:  
     [[ True]
      [ True]
      [False]]
```

Question: how do I use my index to 'delete' the third row (of bboxes)?

I have tried:

```
bboxes = bboxes[index,:]
```

as well as:

```
bboxes = bboxes[boxIDs!=boxIDx,:]
```

Both of which give me the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Sorry if this is dumb - but I'm having trouble here :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occured because your are trying to pass vector instead of array of indices. You could use `reshape(-1)` or `reshape(3)` for your `index`:

```
In [56]: bboxes[index.reshape(-1),:]
Out[56]:
array([[370, 205,  40,  40],
       [200, 100,  40,  40]])

In [57]: bboxes[index.reshape(3),:]
Out[57]:
array([[370, 205,  40,  40],
       [200, 100,  40,  40]])

In [58]: index.reshape(-1)
Out[58]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [59]: index.reshape(-1).shape
Out[59]: (3,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Index` is two dimensional, you have to get rid of the additional dimension, so

```
no_third = bboxes[Index[:,0]] 
# array([[370, 205,  40,  40],
#        [200, 100,  40,  40]])
```